Cleaning up SHA tag names
We have sha1, sha256 and sha512, but sha-2 and sha-3.
Could we rename them to match the canonical SHA-N form that the specifications use?

That indeed seems to make sense… especially, since those “sha256”-alike types could be made into tag-synonyms to be sure no one gets lost along the way. (Btw.: hope you don’t mind the minor tag-edit.)

Yes, synonyms would definitely make sense.

I would disagree; SHA256 and SHA512 are two different hash functions; I'm not certain if lumping them together into a SHA2 category is necessarily the Right Thing.

@poncho, I just meant renaming SHA256 -> SHA-256 (making the former a synonym as e-sushi mentioned).

Oh, "never mind"...

@poncho The amount of time that the difference really matters would be minimal, and it's unlikely that any question that does discuss the difference cannot be found because they are "lumped together". Tags are for aggregating (and empathizing), not separating; tags don't have to catch all meaning.

I renamed them as sha-256 and sha-512 and created synonyms for sha256 and sha512. I also changed sha1 to sha-1 and created the synonym. 
Did I miss any?

Looks like you’ve catched them all. ;)

Looking good, I think
